# Remainder Theorem when Divisor not linear $x-a$

Tags: functions

Upon receiving a question, it seemed to have needed me to use the remainder theorem however for a divisor that was not linear. Now while I could long divide it (or synthetically), I was wondering how $x-a$ would apply to something like $x^2-a$ or in general $x^k-a$. This would be a great help, thank you :)

Comment: Personally, I don't understand what you're trying to say. The description of the problem is fuzzy and imprecise. The only theorem about remainders that I can think of in which the "linearity" (degree = 1, I guess) of the divisor (?) comes into play is [Ruffini's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule). Afterwards, when you say "$\text{stuff}$ applies to $\text{Stuff}$", how *exactly* would "$\text{stuff}$" *apply to* "$\text{Stuff}$" ?  By "calculating the remainder of the polynomial divsion of $\text{Stuff}$ by $\text{stuff}$" ? [continues...]

Comment: [continued...] If so, how is this related to the issue in the previous statement (which looks like not being able to use Ruffini)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the remainder, you substitute $x^{2} = a$ (resp. $x^{k} = a$) in the dividend, and collect the powers.

Comment: Could you apply it to $(x^3+5x-1):(x^2-1)?$

Comment: Modulo $x^2 - 1$, one has $x^3 + 5 x - 1 = x \cdot x^2 + 5 x - 1 \equiv x + 5 x - 1 = 6 x - 1$.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much. +1

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand this solution and the one in the comments didnt exactly help either :(. If one was to substitute $x^2 = a$ then wouldn't you have $2a$? Im sorry, but could you use this as an example? Thanks a ton :)  

$(x^4+5x^3+2x+6)$ divided by $(x^2 -3)$

Comment: I use "$\equiv$" to denote the substitution $x^{2} = 3$. Then we have $x^{4} + 5 x^{3} + 2 x + 6 = (x^2)^2 + 5 x \cdot x^2 + 2 x + 6  \equiv 9+ 15 x + 2 x + 6 = 17 x + 15$.

Comment: Ah yes i see, however, is 17x+15 the final answer? and how does one get the substitution for x? is it just from setting $x^2 - 3 =0$ ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the remainder, you may check it with polynomial long division. I only substituted $3$ for $x^{2}$, no substitution for $x$ alone.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{array}{c|c}
  \hline
  \text{Divisor} & \text{Remainder} \\ \hline
  x-a & f(a) \\[5pt]
  (x-a)(x-b) &
  \frac{x-b}{a-b}f(a)+\frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b) \\[5pt]
  x^2-a^2 &
  \frac{f(a)-f(-a)}{2a}x+\frac{f(a)+f(-a)}{2} \\[5pt]
  (x-a)^{2} & (x-a)f'(a)+f(a) \\[5pt]
  (x-a)(x-b)(x-c) &
  \frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)} f(a)+
  \frac{(x-c)(x-a)}{(b-c)(b-a)} f(b)+
  \frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-a)} f(c) \\[5pt]
  (x-a)^{2} (x-b) &  
  (x-a)^{2} \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{(b-a)^{2}}+
  \frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{a-b} f'(a)+f(a) \\[5pt]
  (x-a)^{3} & \frac{(x-a)^{2}}{2}f''(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+f(a) \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Is there any general case?

Comment: For divisor being a product of **distinct** linear factors, that's closely related to Lagrange interpolation.  In case of power of linear factor, that's related to Taylor series expansion.  Mixed cases are not trivial (or refer to Hermite interpolation for your further interest).