# Why doesn’t polynomial remainder theorem work for quadratic equations?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Theoretically, it should work.

Proof for remainder theorem is:
$$p(x) = q(x) \cdot (x - a) + r$$
$$p(a) = q(a) \cdot (0) + r$$
$$p(a) = r$$

If the same thing is done for quadratic divisor of ($x^2 - a$):
$$p(x) = q(x) \cdot (x^2 - a) + r$$
$$p(\sqrt a) = q(\sqrt a) \cdot (0) + r$$
$$p(\sqrt a) = r$$

Intuitively, I know it wouldn’t because the quotient will have an $x$ term while the evaluation will only get a constant.
But, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you divide a polynomial by a second degree polynomial as $x^2-a$ is, the remainder is a polynomial of degree at most one, so it may be not a constant. Nevertheless, if it is a constant it must be a different one that the one you get after dividing by $x-a$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! If you check the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) for the Polynomial remainder theorem, you will find your answer.

Comment: Please see some examples in my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907200/remainder-theorem-when-divisor-not-linear-x-a/1907264#1907264).